# How load Adsense using Jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, adsense

I'm trying to dynamically load Adsense at a specific point on my Wordpess posts - just before a div class that is manually inserted within the wysiwyg text area on each post. So far, I've used the following ...

```
<?php wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' ); ?>
```

before wp_head, and after:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
$(".example-div").before("Here is the content");
});
</script>
```

In the above example plain text like "here is the content" loads in the desired position, but it doesn't work when I insert the Adsense code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
$(".example-div").before("<script type="text/javascript"><!--
google_ad_client = "ca-pub-************";
/* Ad ID */
google_ad_slot = "********";
google_ad_width = 320;
google_ad_height = 50;
//-->
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"
src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js">
</script>");
});
</script>
```

Any suggestions on what modficiations are required - or best way to make the Adsense code appear - greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why not just put the script directly in the page, rather than put in a script that tries to add a script?  The location of the script has nothing to do with the location of anything it adds to the page.

Comment: Also I had quite the bad experience with manual async loading of ad-scripts. I'm not even sure how this goes with the Google TOS, since you aren't loading the script on pageview.

Comment: Can you elaborate ... I'm a novice at this stuff so apologies if what follows doesn't add up. The point at which I'm trying to place the Adsense code is roughly in the middle of each post. It needs to go directly before a div that's added manually on each post, but I want the Adsense to load automatically. Should I be adding the script on a file like content-post.php or single.php (it's Canvas from WooThemes) … how would I position it before the div?